# batch file to segregate files based on a specific string, occurring anywhere, in a filename

Tags: batch-file

I want to move files in the folder c:\test (all are .wav files), containing string 'ooc' occurring anywhere in the filename. I have written a batch file for the same:

```
@echo off
cd C:\test
FOR /R %completepath% %%G IN (*ooc*.wav) DO
(
move /-y "C:\test\*.wav" "C:\ooc\"
)
```

However, this is not working. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you want is this:

```
@echo off
cd C:\test
FOR /R %completepath% %%G IN (*ooc*.wav) DO (
    move /-y "%%G" "C:\ooc\"
)
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly, Thanks !

Comment: That cannot be correct - The MOVE command as written will only succeed if `%completepath%` is empty. That variable should be removed from the MOVE command.

Answer (score 1):

Moving one file at a time by iterating all files:

```
for /r %completepath% %%F in (*ooc*.wav) do move /-y "%%F" "c:\ooc\"
```

Moving whole folders at a time by iterating folders:

```
for /r %completepath% %%F in (.) do if exist *ooc*.wav move /-y "%%~fF\*ooc*.wav" "c:\ooc\"
```

You could remove the IF and redirect stderr to NUL to hide any "cannot find the file specified" error message, but then all potential error messages will be obscured.

```
for /r %completepath% %%F in (.) do move /-y "%%~fF\*ooc*.wav" "c:\ooc\" 2>nul
```